# pandas Dataframe: How to reshape a single column, converting every n rows to a new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How could I convert a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
A = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]
dfA = pd.DataFrame(A)
```

[image]

to a new dataframe like this:

```
# Expect output:
B = [[0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3,4]]
dfB = pd.DataFrame(B)
```

[image]

Comment: `dfA` has only 20 values but `dfB` has 25?

Comment: ```pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(dfA.to_numpy(),(-1,4)))```. as @QuangHoang mentioned, your columns should be one less

Comment: My mistake, corrected

Comment: as @sammywemmy commented, chained with `.T`: `pd.DataFrame(dfA.values.reshape(-1,4).T)`